# Avoid oom exception with pagination

Tags: java, android, pagination, out-of-memory, rx-java

I'm trying to run a script that needs to loop on every documents of my database (using NoSQL database) and duplicate every documents "x time". I know that because the database could have lot of documents and because we could duplicate them as many time as wished, OOM can occur. I tried to avoid it but it still happening. Could someone help me with this? Here's my code:

```
private void duplicates(int xFirsts, Integer nbOccurrences, DatabaseDuplicator duplicator) {
    if(duplicateAllPatient.get())
        totalPatientsToDuplicate = couchbase.patientManager().count(false, false, null);
    else
        totalPatientsToDuplicate = xFirsts;

    //Limit is to avoid to get an OOM error by getting too much patients from the database.
    int limit = 500;
    int skip = 0;

    List<Patient> patients = couchbase.patientManager().findAll(limit, skip);

    while (patients != null && !patients.isEmpty() && nbPatientsDuplicated < totalPatientsToDuplicate) {
        startDuplication(nbOccurrences, duplicator, patients);
        skip += limit;
        if((skip + limit) > totalPatientsToDuplicate)
            limit = totalPatientsToDuplicate - skip;
        patients = couchbase.patientManager().findAll(limit, skip);
    }
}

private void startDuplication(final Integer nbOccurrences, final DatabaseDuplicator duplicator, final List<Patient> patients) {
    loadingInformation.set("");
    Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber){
            for (int i = 0; i < nbOccurrences; i++){
                duplicator.duplicatePatientsWithTheirMedicalRecords(patients, ToolsActivityViewModel.this);
                subscriber.onNext(i);
            }
        }
    });
    observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                    informUserOnDuplicationProgress();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: I assume because your observable never calls `onCompleted()` so it'll never die? And you never unsubscribe from it either?

Answer (score 0):

Two things: your observable never completes, and you start many of them at once (subscribe happens on a different thread).

Use this:

```
    Observable
    .range(0, nbOccurrences)
    .doOnNext(i -> duplicator.duplicatePatientsWithTheirMedicalRecords(patients, ToolsActivityViewModel.this))
    .doOnNext(i -> informUserOnDuplicationProgress())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .toBlocking()
    .lastOrDefault(null);
```

Comment: I still got OOM at a certain point using this. This happening with occurences > 3500, maybe this is normal? If not I assume that their is another memory leak somewhere inside `duplicatePatientsWithTheirMedicalRecords`.

Comment: I'm using `new Action1(){...}`instead of Lambda expression, does it have an impact? (Java 8 is not set on this project)